# Cual es la diferencia entre usar la clase JUnit y usar la consola para testear?

Tags: java, junit

He usado `JUnit` varias veces, sin embargo, la duda que tengo es, cual es la diferencia entre usar `JUnit` y mostrar algo por consola?

Pongamos 1 ejemplo, si quisiera saber si ordene bien un arreglo de números, el `JUnit` con los métodos `assert` me dirá si esta correcto, pero a la vez si muestro por consola ese arreglo, también veré si está correcto o no, entonces, porque no usar siempre la consola como método de prueba o test? Que hace diferente a `JUnit` que en los libros y en clases me lo mencionan como super util?

Answer (score 1):

Automatización, repetibilidad, "atomización" e integración en el proceso de build y packaging.

Si vas a hacer un programa, probar que funciona y olvidarte de él (por ejemplo una práctica para un profesor), JUnit no te aporta gran cosa. Es un programa sencillo con pocas especificaciones; miras que las cumpla, entregas el programa y a otra cosa.

Pero en la vida real de un programador profesional, escribes un código que es parte de un sistema complejo y a los pocos meses o muchos años hay que modificarlo, y si se modifica hay que probar que no se hayan introducido bugs que hagan perder dinero a tu empresa, y aquí JUnit te da:

- Automatización: Los tests se ejecutan automáticamente, no hay que hacerlos a mano revisando resultados desde pantalla (que aparte de ser lento, puede inducir a error).
- Repetibilidad: Cada vez se ejecutan los mismos tests. Además, los haces sobre la versión **final** de la clase. Si haces el test imprimiendo valores por consola y después eliminas esos mensajes de tu programa, estás haciendo un cambio en tu programa que no vas a comprobar con tu test.
- Atomización: Cada pequeño módulo (idealmente cada clase) se prueba por separado. Eso permite probar más a fondo todos los detalles del funcionamiento de la clase. Si tienes un sistema completo, probar el funcionamiento de todos los casos posibles es mucho más difícil o incluso imposible. Además, cuando se introduce un bug en una clase, idealmente lo detectarás en el test de esa clase con lo cual suele ser más fácil de arreglar.
- Integración: Normalmente los tests son parte del proceso de build y packaging del proyecto; si fallan se para el proceso de forma que hay que corregir los bugs antes de continuar. No son un paso que un programador apurado pueda olvidarse o hacer demasiado deprisa.
- Van con el código: No son un documento de pruebas manuales que igual se ha quedado sin actualizar.

También tiene inconvenientes:

- Hay que escribir los tests y, si la funcionalidad de la clase cambia, actualizarlos.
- No son una panacea. Los tests probarán lo que le digas que pruebe. Si alguna combinación no se prueba y al hacer un cambio esa combinación te causa un bug, no se detectará.
- Se centra en pruebas **unitarias**. En teoría es para testear el funcionamiento de un módulo pequeño (típicamente una clase) aislada de las demás. Eso hace las pruebas más sencillas, pero significa que luego tienes que probar el funcionamiento global ("a mano" o con otros entornos de prueba automáticos orientados a pruebas de sistema).

  - En este caso, la ventaja de JUnit es que te permite probar cada clase más a fondo al inicio del proceso de build; una prueba de sistema es mucho más lenta y muchas veces no es fácil modificar el sistema para simular condiciones especiales.

Answer (score -1):

JUnit es un conjunto de librerías que te permiten testear tus programas realizados, la razón por la que es muy útil es que si bien en programas de una gran sencillez como lo es el ordenamiento de un array podría parecer bastante inútil o poco eficiente lo cierto es que en programas de un tamaño mediano/grande es muy útil debido a que te ahorra muchísimo tiempo de estar pensando un test personalizado para probar todas tus clases y objetos creados, así como si tus algoritmos devuelven los valores esperados entre otras cosas sin tener en cuenta que si cambias algo de tu programa lo más probable es que tengas que estar modificando una o varias lineas de código de tu test y a la larga es muy engorroso y costoso. En cambio JUnit te da la posibilidad de tener una plantilla inicial con varios métodos para crear tus objetos y mediante el uso de métodos `assert` probar lo que necesites, esto es muy fácil dado que en el método `setUp()` se inician todos tus objetos y en los métodos con la etiqueta `@test` podes probar así tus clases, métodos y variables. Por otro lado con JUnit podes probar si se produzco (o no) una determinada excepción que se pueda estar esperando. 
Hay muchas otras herramientas y opciones que te permite la implementación de JUnit en tus programas. Podes ver más sobre JUnit en esta pagina https://junit.org/junit5/ e incluso tenes una "User Guide" que te ayudara en tus dudas y uso de la herramienta. 
Espero haber saldado tu duda. 
Un saludo.

Comment: `te ahorra muchísimo tiempo de estar pensando un test personalizado` Sigues teniendo que pensar qué pruebas y cómo, JUnit no te ahorra eso. `si cambias algo de tu programa lo más probable es que tengas que estar modificando una o varias lineas de código de tu test` También con JUnit tienes que adaptar el test a los cambios del programa. `En cambio JUnit te da la posibilidad de tener una plantilla inicial con varios métodos para crear tus objetos`. Te ahorra escribir ¿cuánto? ¿10 líneas?. Eso no es una ventaja relevante. `En el método setup() se inician todos tus objetos` No necesariamente.